# How to handle Invalid command name error, while executing ("after" script) in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, destroy

I know this question has been raised multiple times here and I have gone through all of them. But I didn't find a clear solution for the problem. I know the reasons for the occurrence of this error. I know that after using `root.destroy()`, there are still some jobs left to be completed and all that stuff.
But I want to know how to stop those "after" jobs?
One of the guys asked to use `try`/`accept` in the code. But he didn't show how to use that.
So could you please give a clear solution for this case? Is there any way to remove this error?
I request you not to mark this question duplicate and don't remove this question please. It's important and I don't have other sources to get my answer.

```
invalid command name "2272867821888time"
    while executing
"2272867821888time"
    ("after" script)
```

Comment: I can try to solve the issue but only when  I have something to work with, So if you could provide a snippet of the code so I can try to reproduce the issue here would be better.  
Also try/except blocks can be used to handle any error. So if you are wondering how to use try/except (Although i don't think that is the case), (but if it is the case here is how to use try/except) :

try:
    somethingHere()
    root.destroy()
    somethingHereAsWell()
except:
     pass

Note i used a broad exception clause to be handle all the issues possible in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs when destroying the window before a callback scheduled with `after` is executed. To avoid this kind of issue, you can store the id returned when scheduling the callback and cancel it when destroying the window, for instance using `protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit_function)`.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    global after_id
    var.set(var.get() + 1)
    after_id = root.after(500, callback)

def quit():
    """Cancel all scheduled callbacks and quit."""
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.pack_propagate(False)
var = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()
callback()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, Tcl/Tk has an `after info` method which is not directly accessible through the python wrapper but can be invoked using `root.tk.eval('after info')` and returns a string of ids: `'id1 id2 id3'`. So an alternative to keeping track of all ids is to use this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    var.set(var.get() + 1)
    root.after(500, callback)

def quit():
    """Cancel all scheduled callbacks and quit."""
    for after_id in root.tk.eval('after info').split():
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.pack_propagate(False)
var = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()
callback()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I use the "after info" method i.e. root.tk.eval('after info'), then is there still need of "callback" function and "root.protocol" method?

Comment: @AdnanAkram I have put a full example for the second case. `callback()` is just an example of repeated use of `.after`, what is no longer needed is the `after_id` variable, i.e. you don't need to store the ids of all the callbacks you schedule. `root.protocol` is always needed because it is how you overwrite the closing of the window with the `quit()` function.