# Invalid command name error after destroying window in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am using [CustomTkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) Ui library to create my school project. I have a login system that destroys the current window and creates a new window when the login is successful. However, it gives the following error.

```
invalid command name "140374651695040check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"140374651695040check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "140374651691712click_animation"
    while executing
"140374651691712click_animation"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "140374651695744update"
    while executing
"140374651695744update"
    ("after" script)
```

My code for login is

```
def login(self):
        con=sqlite3.connect(database=r'ims.db')
        cur=con.cursor()

        try:
            if self.uid.get()=="" or self.password.get()=="":
                messagebox.showerror("Error","All fields are required",parent=self.root)
            else:
                cur.execute("select utype,uid from user where uid=? AND pass=?",(self.uid.get(),self.password.get()))
                user=cur.fetchone()
                uid=user[1]
                if user==None:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error","Invalid username/password",parent=self.root)
                elif user[0]=='Admin':
                    self.root.destroy()
                    obj=Admin(uid)
                    obj.mainloop()
                else:
                    self.root.destroy()
                    obj=User(uid)
                    obj.mainloop()  
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f'Error due to : {str(ex)}',parent=self.root)
```

I know this error happens because even though the window is destroyed different methods are still running. I had similar problem in my previous project which I fixed using **after_cancel()** but that time method that was running was function I had made so I knew where it was so It was easy to fix. But this time I don't know how to fix this issue, I think this issue is due to the method of CustomTkinter running even after destroying the window. Also, I am sorry for my English if you are not sure about mu qwery ask me, I will do my best to explain it.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628566/how-to-handle-invalid-command-name-error-while-executing-after-script-in-tk) but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or` Should be `if self.uid.get() =="" and self.password.get()=="":`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently that was solved by using `self.root.quit()` instead of `destroy()`

E.G.:

```
try:
    if self.uid.get() == "" or self.password.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error",
            "All fields are required",
            parent=self.root
        )
    else:
        cur.execute(
            "select utype,uid from user where uid=? AND pass=?",
            (self.uid.get(), self.password.get())
        )
        user = cur.fetchone()
        uid = user[1]

        if user is None:  # editorial - use 'is' when comparing with 'None'
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Error","Invalid username/password",
                parent=self.root
            )
        elif user[0] == 'Admin':
            self.root.quit()  # change here...
            obj = Admin(uid)
            obj.mainloop()
        else:
            self.root.quit()  # ...and here
            obj = User(uid)
            obj.mainloop()
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this but I have already used quit() method but it didn't work. Not only error still shows up, login window also doesn't close.