# Invalid command name while executing - tk- python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, customtkinter

Edit: updated code

I want to run several TK class instances, consecutively from another python file. To achieve this, I have created a TK class in a python file named `GUI_file.py`

```
import os
import cv2
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Canvas, PhotoImage


class GUI(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self, id):
       super().__init__()
       self.title("Front-end UI")
       self.geometry(f"{1080}x{720}")

       # configure grid layout (4x4)
       self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
       self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
       self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
       self.image_window = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
       self.image_window.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=40, sticky="nsew")

       self.image_path = os.path.join(Path().absolute() / 'dependent_data', "poo.png")
       self.org_image = cv2.imread(self.image_path)
       self.canvas = Canvas(self.image_window, width=1280, height=720, background="white")
       self.canvas.pack()
       self.canvas_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.image_path))
       self.canvas.create_image(625, 350, image=self.canvas_image, anchor="center")
       # initialize and do something with id
       self.id = id
       self.exit = False
       self.after_method()

    def method1(self):
       self.id += 1
       # do something

    def method2(self, img):
       cv2.line(img, (self.id, self.id), (self.id, self.id), (0,0,255), 2)
       self.canvas_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)))
       self.canvas.create_image(625, 350, image=self.canvas_image, anchor="center")
       self.method1()
       # do something

    def after_method(self):
       if self.exit or self.id >= 100:
          # save results
          self.destroy()
          return
       
       self.method2(self.org_image.copy())
       print(self.id)
       self.after(10, self.after_method)
       
    def method3(self):
       pass
       # do soemthing


def run_instance(id):
    gui = GUI(id)
    gui.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", sys.exit)
    gui.mainloop()
    print("Finished running instance....")
```

And I'm calling the method `run_instance()` in another file: `another.py`

```
# neceassry imports
from GUI_file import run_instance

# list of ids

for id in ids:
   run_instance(id)
   # process saved results from instance
   # pause(5)
```

When a new instance is initiated, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/user/project/gui/GUI_file.py", line 803, in update
    self.destroy()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/ctk_tk.py", line 85, in destroy
    tkinter.Tk.destroy(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2341, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
invalid command name "139702252461440update"
    while executing
"139702252461440update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "139702258075584<lambda>"
    while executing
"139702258075584<lambda>"
    ("after" script)
...
invalid command name "139702256197312<lambda>"
    while executing
"139702256197312<lambda>"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "139702494947200check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"139702494947200check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
```

My aim is to run a new separate instance for each id without user intervention.

I have tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630091/14301371) and got a similar error:

```
# neceassry imports

Class GUI():
    def __init__(self, id):
       # initialize and do something with id

    def method1(self):
       # do something

    def method2(self):
       # do something

    def quit(self):
       for after_id in self.tk.eval('after info').split():
          self.after_cancel(after_id)
       self.destroy()
  
    def after_method(self):
       if self.exit:
          # save results
          self.quit()
       
       self.method2()
       self.after(10, self.after_method)
       
    def method3(self):
       # do something


def run_instance(id):
    gui = GUI(id)
    gui.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", gui.quit)
    gui.mainloop()
    print("Finished running instance....")
```

I have also tried `self.quit()`, `exit()` (just runs one instance and exits the kernel) and `tkinter.Tk.quit()` inplace of `self.destory` and it didn#t seems to solve the error.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: When you quit the app in the after method you should put a `return` statement after it otherwise the code will just keep on going, and since you've just destroyed your application/widget this error will be thrown. This is happening because `self.destroy()` doesn't quit the programm but just, well, destroys your window/widget

Comment: oh I didn't see see that you called gui.quit directly cause in that case you need to set `self.exit` to `True` and `return` in the after method since `.after` doesn't stop when you destroy the window/widget itself, cause it's not directly bound to the window or widget. It's part of the tkinter framework, and its scheduled tasks continue to run until they complete or are canceled using `.after_cancel`.

Comment: Comments in Python start with `#`. In order to make your [MRE]s easy to run, please use the correct way to comment out lines (I know this code won't run anyway, but keep in mind for other questions :) )

Comment: This is the sort of error you'll get when you have more than one instance of Tk. I don't see anywhere in your code where you use actual threads. Simply creating multiple instances of `Tk` and using `after` is _not_ multithreading. It's all just a single thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, I know that its not multithreading and I was not aiming to do it. I want to run one instance of `GUI` close if after `self.exit` is `True` and keep doing this for all the `ids`.

Comment: `GUI` does not inherit from any `customtkinter` or `tkinter` widget, so I wonder why something like `self.tk.eval(...)`, `self.destroy()`, etc work.  It is better to provide a [mre] in order to identify the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 I have updated the code. Hope this help.

Comment: The updated code should exit the application immediately after closing the first instance because `sys.exit()` is called.

Comment: Try adding `return` after `self.destroy()` inside `after_method()`.